# Create class in Microsoft Teams "Microsoft 365 for business"

Tags: office365, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

It is possible to create teams with type `"class"` if i have license 365 business?
Can i change from license business to education ?

```
 if yes how i can do this?
```

Comment: Are you talking about [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-a-class-team-in-microsoft-teams-fae422eb-58b7-4431-9ff2-a4b9b6ae7c5b) ?

Comment: yes, but my license is business i can't select type "class"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No
it is not possible to use the [Teams for Education](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/microsoft-teams-5aa4431a-8a3c-4aa5-87a6-b6401abea114?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) features such as Teams Class or the grid-view in regular business tenants.

Also it is not possible to switch a tenant from one type to another.

For registered Microsoft partners it is possible to create a 90 day edu tenant on transform.microsoft.com  *'to help you showcase and highlight Microsoft Education products to your customers including Microsoft Teams ...'*

The https://transform.microsoft.com site uses the Microsoft Partner Center for authentication. Partners are required to be enrolled with the Microsoft Partner Center https://partner.microsoft.com to access the site.